# Is is possible to to make several different IP point to the same machine?

Tags: windows-xp, ip, mac-address, mapping

If the answer is possible,how?

DNS is not for this kind of job,obviously.

**UPDATE**

Can someone answer this question:

domain name : IP -> DNS;

IP : Mac -> ??

Comment: I think you better clarify your update, as that is not a question and therefore cannot be answered.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course it is. You can add an alias for your NIC that gets a different IP adress or add a second NIC with a different IP.

How this is done varies with the OS used, which you didn't state.

Comment: Do you mean I need to have multiple NIC to host multiple IP address?

Comment: @apache: No. You can have multiple IP addresses on a single NIC.

Comment: How's it added ? What's the name of that X(device?) to add it(like DNS)?

Comment: maybe if you told us your operating system, that might help.

Comment: I'm using windows XP, using ADSL. I doubt how I can add/change the IP without authentication.

Comment: ah, if you're using adsl then simply adding the extra IPs to your existing NIC may very well not do what you need - your adsl provider needs to know that you're exposing multiple IPs over their connection to route correctly.

Comment: OK, if you try to get a second public IP address for your DSL line, you are probably out of luck as I never heard of any provider who would offer that. Please extend your original question with some info on what you want to do and why.

Comment: @SvenW,can you answer this question: domain name -> IP : DNS;IP -> Mac : ??

Comment: @apache: If I'm reading your symbols correct, I believe you're asking what translates an IP address to MAC address? That would be ARP, Address Resolution Protocol.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question. Domain name and DNS are the same for me, and I don't see how the MAC address matters here. Please try to explain what you want to do.

Comment: ARP is a protocal, where is the IP-to-MAC information restored?

Comment: You are right, ARP is a protocol which works on the local (Ethernet) network only, not beyond it: Some system want's to send a packet to 192.168.1.100 and sends a broadcast: Who was this adress? The system with this address then sends an answer: I have, you can reach me with this MAC adress. Then the sender sends an ethernet packet to the MAC address it received and stores this info in it's ARP cache so it doesn't have to ask every time. Again, please explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, go to the properties of your network connection, then in the TCP/IP properties, then click "Advanced". You can add additional IP addresses there.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy an IP Pool from your ISp and ask them to bind the IP pool to your master IP. They will update on their DNS so any query for any of the IP addresses in the pool will come to you. Nice way of separating services.